# Under the Gregorian calendar, what days can never be Easter?

Tags: soft-question, calendar-computations

Obviously, October 31 can't be Easter any year whatsoever. Indeed no day in October can be Easter. But can February 28 be Easter? What about February 29? May 1? Is there a single consecutive range of days that can't be Easter, like say for example April 17 wrapping around past December to January and over to March 12?

Bonus question: using the Julian calendar as it was observed in Russia until 1918, does the answer to this question change merely by a simple transposition?

Comment: See [ecclesiastical full moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastical_full_moon) and [computus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus).

Comment: @Lucian Do you have a more reliable source than that? Even if those Wikipedia articles are *technically* correct, the writing looks awful.

Comment: Since the Julian calendar shifts with respect to the mean tropical year (hence with respect to the equinoctes) by one day every 128 years, there is no day in the Julian calendar that isn't _eventually_ an Easter.

Comment: @Eric Yes, of course, which is why I wrote "as it was observed in Russia until 1918." I can't promise you David's bounty, but I do hope someone comes along to give a better answer so that Dave doesn't have to reluctantly let the system auto-award it to the reluctant mathematician.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:  Gregorian Easters (eventually) fall on each date in [22 March, 25 April].  Greek Orthodox (Julian) Easters (eventually) fall on each date in the year, including 29 February.

In the years 1919 through 2285, the following years will be the first occurrence of Easter (Gregorian) for each date:

- 22 March, 2285
- 23 March, 2008
- 24 March, 1940
- 25 March, 1951
- 26 March, 1967
- 27 March, 1921
- 28 March, 1937
- 29 March, 1959
- 30 March, 1975
- 31 March, 1929
- 1 April, 1923
- 2 April, 1961
- 3 April, 1983
- 4 April, 1920
- 5 April, 1931
- 6 April, 1947
- 7 April, 1985
- 8 April, 1928
- 9 April, 1939
- 10 April, 1955
- 11 April, 1971
- 12 April, 1925
- 13 April, 1941
- 14 April, 1963
- 15 April, 1979
- 16 April, 1922
- 17 April, 1927
- 18 April, 1954
- 19 April, 1981
- 20 April, 1919
- 21 April, 1935
- 22 April, 1962
- 23 April, 2000
- 24 April, 2011
- 25 April, 1943

Consequently, every date in the range given by @reluctant mathematician in his answer occurs by 2285.

We could credibly argue whether 22 March will ever actually be a Gregorian Easter since the shortening of times that calendars in use suggests that the Gregorian calendar may be replaced by that time.  No other dates are Easters through they year 10000 under the Gregorian Calendar.

Greek Orthodox Easter is celebrated according to the Julian Calendar.  (This may or may not be the same calendar as in use in Russia up to 1918, I am unable to get definitive data from the implementation described below.)  It takes about 10000 years for this calendar to shift just under three months, so I used the same method but on a time window from 1919 to 50000.  This gives the table of all 366 dates (including 29 February in 42460):

- 1 January, 33809
- 2 January, 33972
- 3 January, 33904
- 4 January, 34189
- 5 January, 34341
- 6 January, 34436
- 7 January, 34531
- 8 January, 34626
- 9 January, 34721
- 10 January, 34968
- 11 January, 35063
- 12 January, 35158
- 13 January, 35405
- 14 January, 35500
- 15 January, 35595
- 16 January, 35785
- 17 January, 35937
- 18 January, 36032
- 19 January, 36127
- 20 January, 36222
- 21 January, 36317
- 22 January, 36564
- 23 January, 36659
- 24 January, 36754
- 25 January, 37001
- 26 January, 37096
- 27 January, 37191
- 28 January, 37381
- 29 January, 37533
- 30 January, 37628
- 31 January, 37723
- 1 February, 37818
- 2 February, 37913
- 3 February, 38160
- 4 February, 38255
- 5 February, 38350
- 6 February, 38749
- 7 February, 38692
- 8 February, 38787
- 9 February, 38977
- 10 February, 39129
- 11 February, 39224
- 12 February, 39319
- 13 February, 39414
- 14 February, 39509
- 15 February, 39756
- 16 February, 39851
- 17 February, 39946
- 18 February, 40345
- 19 February, 40288
- 20 February, 40383
- 21 February, 40573
- 22 February, 40725
- 23 February, 40820
- 24 February, 40915
- 25 February, 41010
- 26 February, 41105
- 27 February, 41352
- 28 February, 41447
- 29 February, 42460
- 1 March, 41542
- 2 March, 41884
- 3 March, 42047
- 4 March, 41979
- 5 March, 42169
- 6 March, 42321
- 7 March, 42579
- 8 March, 42511
- 9 March, 42606
- 10 March, 42701
- 11 March, 43100
- 12 March, 43043
- 13 March, 43138
- 14 March, 43480
- 15 March, 43643
- 16 March, 43575
- 17 March, 43765
- 18 March, 43917
- 19 March, 44175
- 20 March, 44107
- 21 March, 44202
- 22 March, 44544
- 23 March, 44859
- 24 March, 44639
- 25 March, 44734
- 26 March, 45076
- 27 March, 45239
- 28 March, 45171
- 29 March, 45361
- 30 March, 45513
- 31 March, 45771
- 1 April, 45703
- 2 April, 45893
- 3 April, 46140
- 4 April, 2010
- 5 April, 1942
- 6 April, 1980
- 7 April, 1991
- 8 April, 1923
- 9 April, 1939
- 10 April, 1966
- 11 April, 1920
- 12 April, 1931
- 13 April, 1947
- 14 April, 1963
- 15 April, 1928
- 16 April, 1922
- 17 April, 1955
- 18 April, 1971
- 19 April, 1925
- 20 April, 1919
- 21 April, 1946
- 22 April, 1979
- 23 April, 1995
- 24 April, 1927
- 25 April, 1943
- 26 April, 1970
- 27 April, 1924
- 28 April, 1935
- 29 April, 1951
- 30 April, 1967
- 1 May, 1921
- 2 May, 1926
- 3 May, 1959
- 4 May, 1975
- 5 May, 1929
- 6 May, 1945
- 7 May, 2051
- 8 May, 1983
- 9 May, 2173
- 10 May, 2268
- 11 May, 2583
- 12 May, 2515
- 13 May, 2610
- 14 May, 2705
- 15 May, 3104
- 16 May, 3047
- 17 May, 3142
- 18 May, 3332
- 19 May, 3647
- 20 May, 3579
- 21 May, 3769
- 22 May, 3864
- 23 May, 4179
- 24 May, 4111
- 25 May, 4206
- 26 May, 4301
- 27 May, 4700
- 28 May, 4643
- 29 May, 4738
- 30 May, 4928
- 31 May, 5243
- 1 June, 5175
- 2 June, 5365
- 3 June, 5460
- 4 June, 5775
- 5 June, 5707
- 6 June, 5802
- 7 June, 5992
- 8 June, 6459
- 9 June, 6239
- 10 June, 6334
- 11 June, 6524
- 12 June, 6839
- 13 June, 6771
- 14 June, 6961
- 15 June, 7056
- 16 June, 7371
- 17 June, 7303
- 18 June, 7493
- 19 June, 7588
- 20 June, 8055
- 21 June, 7835
- 22 June, 7930
- 23 June, 8120
- 24 June, 8435
- 25 June, 8367
- 26 June, 8557
- 27 June, 8652
- 28 June, 8899
- 29 June, 8994
- 30 June, 9089
- 1 July, 9184
- 2 July, 9499
- 3 July, 9431
- 4 July, 9526
- 5 July, 9716
- 6 July, 10031
- 7 July, 9963
- 8 July, 10153
- 9 July, 10248
- 10 July, 10495
- 11 July, 10590
- 12 July, 10685
- 13 July, 10780
- 14 July, 11095
- 15 July, 11027
- 16 July, 11122
- 17 July, 11312
- 18 July, 11627
- 19 July, 11559
- 20 July, 11749
- 21 July, 11844
- 22 July, 12091
- 23 July, 12186
- 24 July, 12281
- 25 July, 12376
- 26 July, 12691
- 27 July, 12623
- 28 July, 12718
- 29 July, 12908
- 30 July, 13223
- 31 July, 13155
- 1 August, 13345
- 2 August, 13440
- 3 August, 13687
- 4 August, 13782
- 5 August, 13877
- 6 August, 13972
- 7 August, 14287
- 8 August, 14219
- 9 August, 14314
- 10 August, 14504
- 11 August, 14819
- 12 August, 14751
- 13 August, 14941
- 14 August, 15036
- 15 August, 15283
- 16 August, 15378
- 17 August, 15473
- 18 August, 15568
- 19 August, 15883
- 20 August, 15815
- 21 August, 15910
- 22 August, 16100
- 23 August, 16415
- 24 August, 16347
- 25 August, 16537
- 26 August, 16632
- 27 August, 16879
- 28 August, 16974
- 29 August, 17069
- 30 August, 17164
- 31 August, 17479
- 1 September, 17411
- 2 September, 17506
- 3 September, 17848
- 4 September, 18011
- 5 September, 17943
- 6 September, 18133
- 7 September, 18228
- 8 September, 18475
- 9 September, 18570
- 10 September, 18665
- 11 September, 18760
- 12 September, 19075
- 13 September, 19007
- 14 September, 19102
- 15 September, 19444
- 16 September, 19607
- 17 September, 19539
- 18 September, 19729
- 19 September, 19824
- 20 September, 20071
- 21 September, 20166
- 22 September, 20261
- 23 September, 20356
- 24 September, 20671
- 25 September, 20603
- 26 September, 20793
- 27 September, 21040
- 28 September, 21203
- 29 September, 21135
- 30 September, 21325
- 1 October, 21420
- 2 October, 21667
- 3 October, 21762
- 4 October, 21857
- 5 October, 21952
- 6 October, 22199
- 7 October, 22294
- 8 October, 22389
- 9 October, 22636
- 10 October, 22799
- 11 October, 22731
- 12 October, 22921
- 13 October, 23016
- 14 October, 23263
- 15 October, 23358
- 16 October, 23453
- 17 October, 23548
- 18 October, 23795
- 19 October, 23890
- 20 October, 23985
- 21 October, 24232
- 22 October, 24395
- 23 October, 24327
- 24 October, 24517
- 25 October, 24612
- 26 October, 24859
- 27 October, 24954
- 28 October, 25049
- 29 October, 25144
- 30 October, 25391
- 31 October, 25486
- 1 November, 25581
- 2 November, 25828
- 3 November, 25991
- 4 November, 25923
- 5 November, 26113
- 6 November, 26208
- 7 November, 26455
- 8 November, 26550
- 9 November, 26645
- 10 November, 26740
- 11 November, 26987
- 12 November, 27082
- 13 November, 27177
- 14 November, 27424
- 15 November, 27587
- 16 November, 27519
- 17 November, 27709
- 18 November, 27804
- 19 November, 28051
- 20 November, 28146
- 21 November, 28241
- 22 November, 28336
- 23 November, 28583
- 24 November, 28678
- 25 November, 28773
- 26 November, 29020
- 27 November, 29183
- 28 November, 29115
- 29 November, 29305
- 30 November, 29400
- 1 December, 29647
- 2 December, 29742
- 3 December, 29837
- 4 December, 29932
- 5 December, 30179
- 6 December, 30274
- 7 December, 30369
- 8 December, 30616
- 9 December, 30779
- 10 December, 30711
- 11 December, 30901
- 12 December, 31148
- 13 December, 31243
- 14 December, 31338
- 15 December, 31433
- 16 December, 31528
- 17 December, 31775
- 18 December, 31870
- 19 December, 31965
- 20 December, 32212
- 21 December, 32375
- 22 December, 32307
- 23 December, 32592
- 24 December, 32744
- 25 December, 32839
- 26 December, 32934
- 27 December, 33029
- 28 December, 33124
- 29 December, 33371
- 30 December, 33466
- 31 December, 33561

It is of course exceedingly unlikely that any calendrical system, even the Julian system, will remain in use until 46140, the first (Gregorian) year Easter will fall on (Gregorian) 3 April.

### Appendix

I used the Mathematica functions EasterSunday[] and EasterSundayGreekOrthodox[].  As of Version 10, these functions were crippled by Wolfram.  Mathematica documentation claims "As of Version 10.0, calendar functionality is built into the Wolfram Language".  However, there is no equivalent facility, nor is there documentation of a workaround.  I have consequently used https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75281/eastersunday-replacement-in-mathematica-10 to workaround Wolfram's stupidity.

The Greek Orthodox version of the above was created using

```
dates = DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`EasterSundayGreekOrthodox /@ Range[1919, 50000]
days = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[dates[[All, {2, 3}]]]]
findDates[day_] := Select[dates, #[[2]] == day[[1]] && #[[3]] == day[[2]] &][[1]]
result = findDates /@ days)
Length[result]
Max[result[[All, 1]]]
months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
StringJoin @@ (" * " <> ToString[#[[3]]] <> " " <> months[[#[[2]]]] <> ", " <> ToString[#[[1]]] <> "\n" &) /@ result
```

Comment: Side question: if humans are still living on this planet in 2285, what sort of calendar do you think they'll be using? Stardates? Or just some tweaks on the Gregorian calendar just major enough to be considered different from Gregorian?

Comment: @DavidR. : We could just keep using Gregorian to 2285, but it seems likely that something will change.  Perhaps the fallout of global water warfare will return us to "Year 10 of Thog's rule" calendars.  Optimistically, I like to imagine at some point the economic costs of civil time and astronomical calendars will drive the move to atomic timekeeping, eschewing of timezones, and some sort of uniformization of the calendar (i.e. all units a fixed multiple of other units).

Answer (score 7):

Easter is defined (on the Gregorian calendar) as "the first Sunday following the first full moon after the spring equinox". The spring equinox ranges from Mar 20-21. The lunar cycle is 29.53 days. The dominical ranges from 1-7. Thus, Easter will be no later than Apr 25. The earliest is Mar 22.

Comment: So then each day between March 22 and April 25 (inclusive) will be Easter at least once within the next four centuries?

Comment: This calculation will work most of the time. In some religions, observers watch for the full moon and then name the date. Their full moon can be different from the astronomical full moon. (human error?)

Comment: The Catholic Church computes Easter using the ecclesiastical full moon, a straightforward (though somewhat verbose) formula that obviates any need for observation or for detailed computation of when the Moon actually becomes full.

Comment: (loosely stated) the first full moon on or after the vernal equinox; also, if that calculation coincides with Passover, then Easter will be a week later.

Comment: @mlchristians, is there any evidence that Easter is moved when it coincides with Passover? I've seen various calculations for the date of Easter, and can't see any evidence that Passover itself is calculated, let alone that it causes Easter to be moved.

Comment: @Steve I've seen it different places---one I recall, ``On the History and Practice of Ancient Astronomy'' by J. Evans. You bring up a good point about the calculation of Passover.

Comment: @mlchristians, yes certainly I've heard this claim before in my own research, but it appears possibly to be (and I mean no disrespect to you in saying this...) one of the misleading claims that swirls around this topic. It's possible that the calculation adopted by the Christian church inherently avoids Passover (perhaps by the rule that Easter is the Sunday *after* the full moon - that full-moon day perhaps being Passover itself by the Judaic calculation, idk), but there is definitely no ad-hoc exception to the calculation, or specific reference to Passover as part of the calculation.

Comment: @Steve Then I can only refer you to what was promulgated at the Council of Nicea in 325 A.D. if you can find an accurate reference to it. Note that in my original comment, I had said "loosely stated"---if you replace "vernal equinox" with "March 21" you will have a more accurate statement of what the Church decreed back in 325 A.D. I hope this helps.

Comment: @mlchristians, prior to Dionysius, who formalised the computus for Easter in around 500AD, the church possibly used a different method of reckoning. I can't speak offhand to what exactly preceded it. I can only tell you that I'm not aware of any such exception in the Gregorian system, or in the Julian system that immediately preceded it. As I say, a possible explanation is that the "Sunday after" rule inherently avoids Passover - because the Jewish scheme for calculating Passover, is similar if not identical to how the "Paschal full moon" is calculated in the Christian system.

Comment: That is, (and I speak as someone who is not familiar with the detail of the Jewish lunar calendar), if the Paschal full moon determined by the Christian computus *is* the same day as Passover in the Jewish calendar, then the rule which says Gregorian Easter is always the *Sunday after* the full moon (and this is not an exception, but an inherent part of the calculation, because the full moon itself is only occasionally on a Sunday, so Easter would usually be on the Sunday after the full moon, given that Easter axiomatically falls on Sunday), inherently avoids Easter falling on Passover itself.